# How to get sender mailbox from email.message.Message object?

Tags: python, email

First I connect to my own mailbox using such code:

```py
import email
import imaplib

imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
imap_server.login("myemail", "mypassword")
imap_server.select('inbox')
```

Then I get the last email on it in the way like:

```py
_, data = imap_server.search(None, 'ALL')
id_list = data[0].split()

_, data = imap_server.fetch(id_list[-1], '(RFC822)')
rawmail = data[0][1]
prev_mail = email.message_from_bytes(rawmail)
```

And after that, I need to get sender email from `prev_mail` variable. 
I tried it myself a little bit, and figured out that `prev_mail['From']` is usually sth like this: `"John Snow" <johnsnow@gmail.com>`, so that means I can just grab the `<*>` part and use it.

But the question is: will it always be like this so I could use my method? And are there any better ways to do this rather than mine?

EDIT:

> There are multiple variants of From: headers. Python 3.8 has a good parser for this in the email.header module. But perhaps the Return-Path: header would actually be closer to what you really want? - tripleee

Thank you very much, tripleee, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: There are multiple variants of `From:` headers. Python 3.8 has a good parser for this in the `email.header` module. But perhaps the `Return-Path:` header would actually be closer to what you really want?

Comment: Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/58263962/874188